# Force user to type a regex on input

Tags: regex, angular, input

I have been trying to do a regexp to force the user to just type what I want in the input and **NOT** display it in the input field. I have try use many events, but the event type it on the input field and have to make an extra validation or found some errors using the code. Never found the correct event.

this is my html file:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someModel" (keydown)="validate($event);">
```

this is my component

```
validateRegex(event: any) {
    let regexp = new RegExp(/^([0-9][0-9]?)(\.([0-9][0-9]?)?)?$/);

    let keyPress = event.key;

    if(!event.ctrlKey && (event.altKey || event.shiftKey)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    if(!event.ctrlKey && keyPress.length < 2) { //Make sure it just press 1 digit, avoid stuff like "backspace"
      if(keyPress == '0' || keyPress == '1' || keyPress == '2' || keyPress == '3' || keyPress == '4' || keyPress == '5'
      || keyPress == '6' || keyPress == '7' || keyPress == '8' || keyPress == '9' || keyPress == '.' ) {
        let test = this.someModel ? this.someModel.toString() + event.key: event.key;
        if (!regexp.test(test)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }
```

Now this validate the user to insert just decimals with 2 digits after and before the dot, also doesn't allow the dot to be on his own. The problem with this code, is that if the user types '99.' and then clicks/arrows backwards to the first 9, he will be able to insert a 9 at the beginning, breaking the regular expression. `event` just only got the key inserted, not sure where is going to be inserted.

If I don't use keydown/keypress the display input will change already, the validation will be made, but the UI will change. In keydown, the UI is still not changed. I don't want to block the user from moving around the input neither

Now yes, I could solve this problem using a mask, but the library mask I got have problems and have some errors too. Shamefully I cannot use any other.

Can this be solve with the proper event or asking for the altered value somehow on the keydown or It is possible to create my own mask and solve this?

Comment: Is it not better to show the user an error below the input that shows whatever they type is in wrong format? Then you can show them, in the error message, what is wrong with the format. As they correct it the error will go away. Its much simpler to implement (validator with regex) and it is less irritating for end user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*html*

```html
<input #input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event);">
```

*ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = '0';
  @ViewChild('input', { static: false }) input;

  onChange(value: string) {
    let regexp = /^([0-9][0-9]?)(\.([0-9][0-9]?)?)?$/;
    if (!value) {
      this.value = '';
    }
    if (!regexp.test(value)) {
      this.input.nativeElement.value = this.value
    } else {
      this.value = value;
    }

  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phfkcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html